# Who chooses the default programs?

Tags: default-programs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are applications selected as defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261/how-are-applications-selected-as-defaults)

I was curious who decides which programs will be the default.  For example thunderbird instead of evolution, or rythmbox instead of miro.

I know how to set default programs this isn't related to that.

I am curious about the specific programs chosen for the distribution at time of packaging the iso and does the community have any way to make suggestions?